Integrate an Arc42 subdocu into main Arc42 docu
I have each services with its own arc42 docus and i want to bind each of them in a global arc42 in sub chapter. How can i achieve this. Is it possible to link defined chapter from external arch42( is in other git-repros) to build one global arc42 docu?
I want to build one arc42 docu by using different arc42 of other sub-systems

I currently see two or three ways to solve your problem. They.somehow depend on the toolchain you use.
If you store and view the docs in github/gitlab, you can simply link between your docs. But I guess this is not the solution you need.
When you use a tool like antora or doctoolchain, you can clone all your sub documents for different repositories into you main repository. You could also use git submodules for this, but I would prefere to clone them from within your build script. For docToolchain, there is a tutorial for this approach (https://doctoolchain.org/docToolchain/v2.0.x/020_tutorial/050_multipleRepositories.html)
A newer approach which I started to use some weeks ago is to render all arc42 docs in their own repositories but with the same toplevel menu. You can then setup the menu in such a way that the emnu entries link to the other remote repositories. Since all habe the same menu, nobody will notice that you jump between the repositories.
Hope this helps.
